# Google Custom Search API capabilities?

Tags: android, google-api

I just wanted to know about the capabilities of the custom search api. Specifically, I'm looking for an API that can search google and return me a list of urls for the result. Is it compatible with java? I wanted to know if I can use it for a future application. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to "google it".
There is open source that written by Google that can connect to google API throw JSON.
[Google APIs Client Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list)

It's compatibility with Java 5 (or higher)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are you allowed to use the google api without buying it (for commercial use)?

Comment: I think is better if you will post another question, maybe someone else know